# JavaScript countdown timer for hour, minutes and seconds when a start button click

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create countdown timer for hour,minute and second when a button click. This is my code so far.

HTMLcode

```
<div class="colomn" style="margin-right: 20px">
   <button class="start" onclick="clock();">Start</button>
</div>
```

javascript function

```
<script>
 var myTimer;
 function clock() {
        myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
        var c = 5;

        function myClock() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = --c;
               if (c == 0) {
                   clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
```

This is simple and not showing separate hour,min and sec. How can I apply this for count hour,min and sec. Please help me.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp might help?

Comment: Also a stylized clock -> https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/MwNPVq

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Working Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="countdownTimeStart()">Start Timer</button>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to

function countdownTimeStart(){

var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 25, 2025 15:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All I did was copy the code from the link above, modified it for a button handler, and pasted it. So credit where it is due.

Answer (score 4):

You need a counter for seconds. During each 1 second interval, decrement this counter, and do the necessary calculations.

```
var myTimer;
function clock() {
    myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);
    var c = 3610; //Initially set to 1 hour


    function myClock() {
        --c
        var seconds = c % 60; // Seconds that cannot be written in minutes
        var secondsInMinutes = (c - seconds) / 60; // Gives the seconds that COULD be given in minutes
        var minutes = secondsInMinutes % 60; // Minutes that cannot be written in hours
        var hours = (secondsInMinutes - minutes) / 60;
        // Now in hours, minutes and seconds, you have the time you need.
        console.clear();
        console.log(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds)
        if (c == 0) {
            clearInterval(myTimer);
        }
    }
}

clock();
```

Put it in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6jbntLe/) as well. See if it works..

**EDIT**: Updated the erroneous code. Thanks to @JDrake for pointing the fact out...

Comment: How to count each hour,min and sec. Could you please show the way.

Comment: @ChathuriFernando Updated the answer with the code snippet. That should be good..

Comment: This doesn't work. Set `c` to 10000 and check the result.

Comment: @JDrake corrected the mistake. Thanks for pointing out... (y)

Answer (score 3):

Simple Answer would be as follows, 
html part,

```
<button onclick="clockStart()">Start</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

JS part,

```
function clockStart() {
          setInterval(function() {
                     date = new Date()
                     let hour = date.getHours();
                     let minutes = date.getMinutes();
                     let seconds = date.getSeconds();
                     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hour + ":"+ minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the value in seconds to one in hours, minutes, and seconds:

```js
var secs  = Math.floor(c % 60);
var mins  = Math.floor((c/60) % 60);
var hours = Math.floor((c/(60*60)));
```

This will yield you the amount of seconds left over when removing the minutes (using the modulus operator) and then repeats this for the minutes and hours. You can also easily extend this to include days or weeks:

```js
var hours = Math.floor((c/(60*60)) % 24);
var days = Math.floor((c/(60*60*24) % 7);
var weeks = Math.floor((c/60*60*24*7));
```

Your code does suffer from one downside: if for some reason the calls become slightly further apart, this might increasingly build a delay. You might instead want to use the lines:

```js
endTime = Date.parse(new Date()) + delay;
timeLeft = endTime - Date.parse(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very primordial clock for you:

```
 function clock(t){
    if(clock._stop){return};
    var d = new Date(Date.now());
    console.log(d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes()+":"+d.getSeconds()+":"+d.getMilliseconds())
    window.requestAnimationFrame(clock);
}
    clock._stop = false;
    clock();
```

check your console. To stop the clock do `clock._stop = true`; To start it, set it back to false and call like `clock()`. You can wrap the logic inside an other object with getters/setters or whatever you prefer.

[**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/gn9b5v9s/1/)

Comment: I tried. but not working. Is this possible to add when a button click?

Comment: Can you please update the complete answer. I'm new to the javascript.

Comment: When I copy paste above and open console it logs fine. Of course it is possible to bind it to a button. Do `yourButtonElement.addEventListener("click",function(e){clock._stop = false;clock();},false)`

Comment: Wait I'll make fiddle

Comment: added the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can try this;

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- This will start a timer for 5 hours 6 minutes and 7 seconds -->
    <button onclick="countdown(5,6,7)"> Start </button>
    <div><h3 id="timer"></h3></div>
    <script>
    function countdown(hr,mm,ss)
    {
        var interval = setInterval(function(){

            if(hr == 0 && mm == 0 && ss == 0)clearInterval(interval);
            ss--;
            if(ss == 0)
            {
                ss = 59;
                mm--;
                if(mm == 0)
                {
                    mm = 59;
                    hr--;
                }
            }

            if(hr.toString().length < 2) hr = "0"+hr;
            if(mm.toString().length < 2) mm = "0"+mm;
            if(ss.toString().length < 2) ss = "0"+ss;
            $("#timer").html(hr+" : "+mm+" : "+ss);

        },1000)
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var seconds_inputs =  document.getElementsByClassName('deal_left_seconds');
var total_timers = seconds_inputs.length;
for ( var i = 0; i < total_timers; i++){
    var str_seconds = 'seconds_'; var str_seconds_prod_id = 'seconds_prod_id_';
    var seconds_prod_id = seconds_inputs[i].getAttribute('data-value');
    var cal_seconds = seconds_inputs[i].getAttribute('value');

    eval('var ' + str_seconds + seconds_prod_id + '= ' + cal_seconds + ';');
    eval('var ' + str_seconds_prod_id + seconds_prod_id + '= ' + seconds_prod_id + ';');
}
function timer() {
    for ( var i = 0; i < total_timers; i++) {
        var seconds_prod_id = seconds_inputs[i].getAttribute('data-value');

        var days = Math.floor(eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id) / 24 / 60 / 60);
        var hoursLeft = Math.floor((eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id)) - (days * 86400));
        var hours = Math.floor(hoursLeft / 3600);
        var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours * 3600));
        var minutes = Math.floor(minutesLeft / 60);
        var remainingSeconds = eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id) % 60;

        function pad(n) {
            return (n < 10 ? "0" + n : n);
        }
        document.getElementById('deal_days_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(days);
        document.getElementById('deal_hrs_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(hours);
        document.getElementById('deal_min_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(minutes);
        document.getElementById('deal_sec_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(remainingSeconds);

        if (eval('seconds_'+ seconds_prod_id) == 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('deal_days_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('deal_hrs_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('deal_min_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = document.getElementById('deal_sec_' + seconds_prod_id).innerHTML = pad(0);
        } else {
            var value = eval('seconds_'+seconds_prod_id);
            value--;
            eval('seconds_' + seconds_prod_id + '= ' + value + ';');
        }
    }
}

var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="deal_left_seconds" data-value="1" value="8888888">
                        <div class="box-wrapper">
                            <div class="date box"> <span class="key" id="deal_days_1">00</span> <span class="value">DAYS</span> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-wrapper">
                            <div class="hour box"> <span class="key" id="deal_hrs_1">00</span> <span class="value">HRS</span> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-wrapper">
                            <div class="minutes box"> <span class="key" id="deal_min_1">00</span> <span class="value">MINS</span> </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-wrapper hidden-md">
                            <div class="seconds box"> <span class="key" id="deal_sec_1">00</span> <span class="value">SEC</span> </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="countdownTimeStart()">Start Timer</button>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to

function countdownTimeStart(){

var countDownDate = new Date("Sep 25, 2025 15:00:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
}, 1000);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

getCounter(),setCounter() are the member functions of other class behave as static

```
function startTimer() {
        const seconds = getCounter();
        setCounter(seconds+1);
        console.log(`${getCounter()}s`);
        const iid = setInterval(() => {
            startTimer(); clearInterval(iid);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm try using `Math.floor` function to calculate the time correctly and also use the `setInterval` function to count down every second of the time appropriately. 
 Try this code:

```js
var myTimer;

function clock() {
  var totalSeconds = 5 * 60 * 60; // Change 5 to the desired number of hours

  myTimer = setInterval(myClock, 1000);

  function myClock() {
    var hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((totalSeconds % 3600) / 60);
    var seconds = totalSeconds % 60;

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s";

    totalSeconds--;

    if (totalSeconds < 0) {
      clearInterval(myTimer);
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Countdown Complete!";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="column" style="margin-right: 20px">
  <button class="start" onclick="clock();">Start</button>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <p id="demo"></p>
</div>
```

In the updated code the once the timer is complete the timer is cleared and a message is displayed.

Comment: great, i like your code, im gonna using it, tq bro