# Run a javascript script when a button click is not working

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have a script as following.

```
var time = document.getElementById("picker-dates").value;
time = time.split(':');
var date = new Date();
var countDownDate = date.setHours(time[0], time[1], time[2]);

function countdownTimeStart() {
var x = setInterval(function () {

    // set hours, minutes and seconds, decrease seconds
    var hours = time[0];
    var minutes = time[1];
    var seconds = time[2]--;

    // if seconds are negative, set them to 59 and reduce minutes
    if (time[2] == -1) {
        time[1]--;
        time[2] = 59
    }

    // if minutes are negative, set them to 59 and reduce hours
    if (time[1] == -1) {
        time[0]--;
        time[1] = 59
    }

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    // add leading zero for seconds if seconds lower than 10
    if (seconds < 10) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + "0" + seconds + " ";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds + " ";
    }


    // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    }
}, 1000);}
 countdownTimeStart();
```

So I want to run this script when a button click. I tried it as

```
<button class="start" onclick="countdownTimeStart();">Start</button>
```

But this is not working. How can I get this to work. Can someone help me to solve this.

Comment: if you strip out the guts of `countdownTimeStart()` and just drop an alert (or console.log) in there, does the function get called at all?

Comment: The variable distance is never defined, could you please provide a runable example next time?

Comment: What is the problem with distance variable?could you please tell me

Comment: The variable distance, which is used in the if condition, is never defined, or declared for that mattered. It just pops up in the if condition. What is the distance variable doing and where does it gets its value in the first place before we start to check its value?

Comment: If you could just share the HTML of the picker dates element, I think the code can start working.

Comment: @binDebug This is the HTML for picker dates element " <input type = "text"  id = "picker-dates" />

Comment: Please help me to solve this. I'm new to the javascript

Comment: Answer posted below with details about how and why the script was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is similar to the one you asked for yesterday, except for the fact that it asks for the input hours, minutes and seconds. Link here: 
[JavaScript countdown timer for hour, minutes and seconds when a start button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041474/javascript-countdown-timer-for-hour-minutes-and-seconds-when-a-start-button-cli/50041816#50041816)

You had several parts of the code missing from yesterday, crucially the part where you need to factor in the current date (variable *now*) and the distance for the timer to travel (variable *distance*), subtract now to the entered hours minutes and seconds.

Also taking the input should be done after button click. Hence moved the code where you read the value off the input picker date field into the button click handler.

To that end, here is the working code

1. HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div>Please enter the time in HH:MM:YY</div>
    <input type = "text" id = "picker-dates" />
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <button id="start" class="start" onclick="countdownTimeStart()">Start</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

2. Script

```js
function countdownTimeStart() {
var time = document.getElementById("picker-dates").value;
time = time.split(':');
var date = new Date();
var countDownDate = date.setHours(time[0], time[1], time[2]); 

console.log(countDownDate);
  
  
var x = setInterval(function () {

    // set hours, minutes and seconds, decrease seconds
    var hours = time[0];
    var minutes = time[1];
    var seconds = time[2]--;

    // if seconds are negative, set them to 59 and reduce minutes
    if (time[2] == -1) {
        time[1]--;
        time[2] = 59
    }

    // if minutes are negative, set them to 59 and reduce hours
    if (time[1] == -1) {
        time[0]--;
        time[1] = 59
    }
    
    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    // add leading zero for seconds if seconds lower than 10
    if (seconds < 10) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + "0" + seconds + " ";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + ": " + minutes + ": " + seconds + " ";
    }


    // If the count down is over, write some text
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "00:00:00";
    }
}, 1000);

}
```

Working plunk here: https://plnkr.co/edit/65UL4Tj2gGwpeWBfHbgy?p=preview

Comment: I really appreciate and thank you for your answer. But still not working. I couldn't solve it and stuck here.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Could you please put it on a plunk for us to look at? Or maybe share your entire code?

Comment: I want to run this script when the start button click. But not working

Comment: Would you please try adding the script and HTML code shared above in a HTML and js file, and reference the file and run?