# Alert box appears repeatedly and does not allow user input

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding a countdown. When the user is clicking start without giving any input it appears a box through the alert function which is displaying the message "input needed". If the user is giving any input after the alert message and clicking start the alert box is undesirable appearing again even though the condition do not allow this. Why is that so, what I am doing wrong? I marked the considered are in my JavaScript up.

```
 window.onload = function() {
          //Card
          const card = document.getElementById("card");

          //Buttons
          const editer = document.getElementById("editer");
          const reseter = document.getElementById("reseter");
          const x = document.getElementById("close-btn");
          const starter = document.getElementById("starter");
          const quiter = document.getElementById("quiter");

          //"Select"-elements
          const hoursFromSelector = document.getElementById("edt-hours");
          const minutesFromSelector = document.getElementById("edt-minutes");
          const secondsFromSelector = document.getElementById("edt-seconds");

          //For calculation
          const mainclock = document.getElementById("mainclock");

          let interval = null;
          let hours = 0;
          let minutes = 0;
          let seconds = 0;
          let i = true;

          addEventListener("change", () => {
            mainclock.innerHTML = `${hoursFromSelector.value} : ${minutesFromSelector.value} : ${secondsFromSelector.value}`;
          });

          reseter.addEventListener("click", () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
            mainclock.innerHTML = "00 : 00 : 00";
            hoursFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
            minutesFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
            secondsFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
            starter.innerText = "Start";
          });
          //Considered Area
          starter.addEventListener("click", () => {
              if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
                starter.innerText = "Start";
                clearInterval(interval)
                alert("Input needed");
                return;
              } else if(hours != 0 || minutes != 0 || seconds != 0) {
              card.style.display = "none";
              starter.innerText = "Stop";
              if (!interval) {
                hours = hoursFromSelector.value;
                minutes = minutesFromSelector.value;
                seconds = secondsFromSelector.value;
                interval = setInterval(regulSec, 1000);
              } else {
                clearInterval(interval);
                interval = null;
                starter.innerText = "Resume";
              }
            }
          })

        function regulSec() {
          if (minutes == 0 && hours > 0) {
            hours--;
            minutes = 60;
          }
          if (seconds == 0 && seconds > 0) {
            minutes--;
            seconds = 59;
          } else {
            seconds--;
          }
          h = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
          sec = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
          min = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
          mainclock.innerHTML = `${h} : ${min} : ${sec} `;
          if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
            starter.innerText = "Start";
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
        }

        //Functions without any actual mathematical reference
        //Showing main-card
        editer.addEventListener("click", () => {
          if (i == true) {
            card.style.display = "block";
            i = false;
          } else if (i == false) {
            card.style.display = "none";
            i = true;
          }
        });

        //Closing-button for main-card
        x.addEventListener("click", () => {
          card.style.display = "none";
          i = true;
        });

        quiter.addEventListener("click", () => {
          confirm("Are you sure that you do not want to save your settings?");
          if (true) {
            card.style.display = "none";
            hoursFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
            minutesFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
            secondsFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
            mainclock.innerHTML = "00 : 00 : 00";
          }
        });
        }
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(253, 253, 10, 0.620);
}

#mainboard {
  margin: 45vh;
}

[a] {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  color: black;
  font-size: 120%;
}

#main-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1vh;
}

#card {
  width: 20vh;
  height: 20vh;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #accbee 0%, #e7f0fd 100%);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 60px 40px -7px;
}

#start {
  background-color: #4AC33C;
}

#card-hdng {
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="mainboard">
    <div a id="mainclock">00 : 00 : 00</div>
    <div id="main-btn">
      <button class="button" id="editer">Edit</button>
      <button class="button" id="reseter">Reset</button>
      <button class="starter" id="starter">Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="display:none" id="card">
    <div id="card-hdng">Settings <button id="close-btn">X</button></div>
    <div id="card-items">
      <label for="edt-hours">Hours</label>
      <select id="edt-hours" placeholder="00">
        <option>00</option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        <option>32</option>
        <option>33</option>
        <option>34</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>36</option>
        <option>37</option>
        <option>38</option>
        <option>39</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>41</option>
        <option>42</option>
        <option>43</option>
        <option>44</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>46</option>
        <option>47</option>
        <option>48</option>
        <option>49</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>51</option>
        <option>52</option>
        <option>53</option>
        <option>54</option>
        <option>55</option>
        <option>56</option>
        <option>57</option>
        <option>58</option>
        <option>59</option>
        <option>60</option>
        <option>61</option>
        <option>62</option>
        <option>63</option>
        <option>64</option>
        <option>65</option>
        <option>66</option>
        <option>67</option>
        <option>68</option>
        <option>69</option>
        <option>70</option>
        <option>71</option>
        <option>72</option>
        <option>73</option>
        <option>74</option>
        <option>75</option>
        <option>76</option>
        <option>77</option>
        <option>78</option>
        <option>79</option>
        <option>80</option>
        <option>81</option>
        <option>82</option>
        <option>83</option>
        <option>84</option>
        <option>85</option>
        <option>86</option>
        <option>87</option>
        <option>88</option>
        <option>89</option>
        <option>90</option>
        <option>91</option>
        <option>92</option>
        <option>93</option>
        <option>94</option>
        <option>95</option>
        <option>96</option>
        <option>97</option>
        <option>98</option>
        <option>99</option>
      </select>
      <label for="edt-minutes">Minutes</label>
      <select id="edt-minutes">
        <option>00&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        <option>32</option>
        <option>33</option>
        <option>34</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>36</option>
        <option>37</option>
        <option>38</option>
        <option>39</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>41</option>
        <option>42</option>
        <option>43</option>
        <option>44</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>46</option>
        <option>47</option>
        <option>48</option>
        <option>49</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>51</option>
        <option>52</option>
        <option>53</option>
        <option>54</option>
        <option>55</option>
        <option>56</option>
        <option>57</option>
        <option>58</option>
        <option>59</option>
      </select>
      <label for="edt-seconds">Seconds</label>
      <select id="edt-seconds">
        <option>00&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        <option>32</option>
        <option>33</option>
        <option>34</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>36</option>
        <option>37</option>
        <option>38</option>
        <option>39</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>41</option>
        <option>42</option>
        <option>43</option>
        <option>44</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>46</option>
        <option>47</option>
        <option>48</option>
        <option>49</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>51</option>
        <option>52</option>
        <option>53</option>
        <option>54</option>
        <option>55</option>
        <option>56</option>
        <option>57</option>
        <option>58</option>
        <option>59</option>
      </select>
      <button id="quiter">Quit</button>
      <button class="starter">Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: The brackets aren't balanced properly in the JS code you posted, so it won't run and we can't tell where the problem is. Please fix this.

Comment: Bracket for starter click event handler doesn't seem right. Also, you're doing `button.innerText` but button isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: Probably wasn't too helpful for me say it was super messy. Your post should be further revised. If you are still having the same issue with the revised code snippet, then further explain, if not then it should be an answer.

Comment: I just edit my code

Comment: I was just about to upvote your answer @Shmack ;) `button` should be `starter`, right? And btw,  the additional bracket was obvious. Maybe not helpful but you provided a solution.

Comment: Well, I mean its still unclear. Because there is still some functionality that isn't working.

Comment: Two problems I noticed so far (besides syntax errors): You are checking if the variable for the `hour` is 0, but you should probably be checking to see if the `hoursFromSelector.value` is 0. Also, whenever you check the `hoursFromSelector.value` you need to convert it to a number like so: `parseInt(hoursFromSelector.value)`

Comment: @Shmack So when there are not a users input and  I am clicking at start the box is intended appearing. When I giving any input after this and click at the start button again the alert box will undesirable appear again even though there is now input and the conditions for displaying the alert box is not true actually. The countdown is then not working until I refresh my page give a input and start the timer.

Comment: @fijiwa65 Maybe you should edit the title and description now since the syntax errors are fixed. The remaining problems are the actual issues, right?

Comment: @RichardHenage thank you for your help. But hour and hoursFromSelector are equal so this would not be make a difference or not? The disturbed thing is that the alert box is appearing even when when the user gave a input after the alert box is appeared before

Comment: @fijiwa65 You aren't changing the `hour` variable to match the `hoursFromSelector.value` until after you give the alert, so it has no chance to change from 0. I tested it my way and it started working (though there are other problems afterwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the question: You alert box was firing despite changing the values, because the variables were never being updated when the selectbox was changing. The solution was to add to the event listener (that listened for changes on the select boxes) the updated value to the variable.

Your code with the alert firing:

```
if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0)
{
  starter.innerText = "Start";
  clearInterval(interval)
  alert("Input needed");
  //return; return is unnecessary
}
else if(hours != 0 || minutes != 0 || seconds != 0)
{
  card.style.display = "none";
  starter.innerText = "Stop";
  if (!interval)
  {
    hours = hoursFromSelector.value;
    minutes = minutesFromSelector.value;
    seconds = secondsFromSelector.value;
    interval = setInterval(regulSec, 1000);
  }
  else
  {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
    starter.innerText = "Resume";
  }
}
```

was caused because you never update `seconds`, `minutes`, or `hours`, which is what your code checks for - it was fixed by making the following change below:

```
addEventListener("change", () => {
  if (!(interval))
  {
    hours = Number(hoursFromSelector.value);
    minutes = Number(minutesFromSelector.value);
    seconds = Number(secondsFromSelector.value);
  }
  mainclock.innerHTML = `${hoursFromSelector.value} : ${minutesFromSelector.value} : ${secondsFromSelector.value}`;});
```

Fixes:

1. Fixed missing parenthesis.
2. You need to set hours, minutes, and seconds to the value of their respective selectors, casted to a `Number`, whenever they get updated from the selectbox. As I learned yesterday, using `parseInt` is highly not recommended for a reason I can't recall, other than that `Number` handles more use cases.
3. You need to save the input from the `confirm()` inside the `quiter.addEventListener` listener and use it in the if statement.
4. Inside of the "change" event listener, check to see if interval is null - there was a bug where if the clock was running you could change a select value, and change the value of the clock.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //Card
  const card = document.getElementById("card");

  //Buttons
  const editer = document.getElementById("editer");
  const reseter = document.getElementById("reseter");
  const x = document.getElementById("close-btn");
  const starter = document.getElementById("starter");
  const quiter = document.getElementById("quiter");

  //"Select"-elements
  const hoursFromSelector = document.getElementById("edt-hours");
  const minutesFromSelector = document.getElementById("edt-minutes");
  const secondsFromSelector = document.getElementById("edt-seconds");

  //For calculation
  const mainclock = document.getElementById("mainclock");

  let interval = null;
  let hours = 0;
  let minutes = 0;
  let seconds = 0;
  let i = true;

  addEventListener("change", () => {
    if (!(interval))
    {
      hours = Number(hoursFromSelector.value);
      minutes = Number(minutesFromSelector.value);
      seconds = Number(secondsFromSelector.value);
    }
    mainclock.innerHTML = `${hoursFromSelector.value} : ${minutesFromSelector.value} : ${secondsFromSelector.value}`;
  });

  reseter.addEventListener("click", () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    mainclock.innerHTML = "00 : 00 : 00";
    hoursFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
    minutesFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
    secondsFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
    starter.innerText = "Start";
  });
  //Considered Area
  starter.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
      //button.innerText = "Start";
      starter.innerText = "Start";
      clearInterval(interval)
      alert("Input needed");
    } else if (hours != 0 || minutes != 0 || seconds != 0) {
      card.style.display = "none";
      starter.innerText = "Stop";
      if (!interval) {
        hours = Number(hoursFromSelector.value);
        minutes = Number(minutesFromSelector.value);
        seconds = Number(secondsFromSelector.value);
        interval = setInterval(regulSec, 1000);
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
        starter.innerText = "Resume";
      }
    }
  });

function regulSec() {
  if (seconds > 0) {
    seconds--;
  }
  else if (seconds == 0 && minutes > 0) {
    minutes--;
    seconds = 59;
  }
  else if (seconds == 0 && minutes == 0 && hours > 0) {
    hours--;
    minutes = 59;
    seconds = 59;
  }
  if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0)
  {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
  h = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
  sec = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  min = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  mainclock.innerHTML = `${h} : ${min} : ${sec} `;
}

//Functions without any actual mathematical reference
//Showing main-card
editer.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (i == true) {
    card.style.display = "block";
    i = false;
  } else if (i == false) {
    card.style.display = "none";
    i = true;
  }
});

//Closing-button for main-card
x.addEventListener("click", () => {
  card.style.display = "none";
  i = true;
});

quiter.addEventListener("click", () => {
  k = confirm("Are you sure that you do not want to save your settings?");
  if (k) {
    card.style.display = "none";
    hoursFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
    minutesFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
    secondsFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
    mainclock.innerHTML = "00 : 00 : 00";
  }
});
};
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(253, 253, 10, 0.620);
}

#mainboard {
  margin: 45vh;
}

[a] {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  color: black;
  font-size: 120%;
}

#main-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1vh;
}

#card {
  width: 20vh;
  height: 20vh;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #accbee 0%, #e7f0fd 100%);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 60px 40px -7px;
}

#start {
  background-color: #4AC33C;
}

#card-hdng {
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="mainboard">
    <div a id="mainclock">00 : 00 : 00</div>
    <div id="main-btn">
      <button class="button" id="editer">Edit</button>
      <button class="button" id="reseter">Reset</button>
      <button class="starter" id="starter">Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="display:none" id="card">
    <div id="card-hdng">Settings <button id="close-btn">X</button></div>
    <div id="card-items">
      <label for="edt-hours">Hours</label>
      <select id="edt-hours" placeholder="00">
        <option>00</option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        <option>32</option>
        <option>33</option>
        <option>34</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>36</option>
        <option>37</option>
        <option>38</option>
        <option>39</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>41</option>
        <option>42</option>
        <option>43</option>
        <option>44</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>46</option>
        <option>47</option>
        <option>48</option>
        <option>49</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>51</option>
        <option>52</option>
        <option>53</option>
        <option>54</option>
        <option>55</option>
        <option>56</option>
        <option>57</option>
        <option>58</option>
        <option>59</option>
        <option>60</option>
        <option>61</option>
        <option>62</option>
        <option>63</option>
        <option>64</option>
        <option>65</option>
        <option>66</option>
        <option>67</option>
        <option>68</option>
        <option>69</option>
        <option>70</option>
        <option>71</option>
        <option>72</option>
        <option>73</option>
        <option>74</option>
        <option>75</option>
        <option>76</option>
        <option>77</option>
        <option>78</option>
        <option>79</option>
        <option>80</option>
        <option>81</option>
        <option>82</option>
        <option>83</option>
        <option>84</option>
        <option>85</option>
        <option>86</option>
        <option>87</option>
        <option>88</option>
        <option>89</option>
        <option>90</option>
        <option>91</option>
        <option>92</option>
        <option>93</option>
        <option>94</option>
        <option>95</option>
        <option>96</option>
        <option>97</option>
        <option>98</option>
        <option>99</option>
      </select>
      <label for="edt-minutes">Minutes</label>
      <select id="edt-minutes">
        <option>00&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        <option>32</option>
        <option>33</option>
        <option>34</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>36</option>
        <option>37</option>
        <option>38</option>
        <option>39</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>41</option>
        <option>42</option>
        <option>43</option>
        <option>44</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>46</option>
        <option>47</option>
        <option>48</option>
        <option>49</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>51</option>
        <option>52</option>
        <option>53</option>
        <option>54</option>
        <option>55</option>
        <option>56</option>
        <option>57</option>
        <option>58</option>
        <option>59</option>
      </select>
      <label for="edt-seconds">Seconds</label>
      <select id="edt-seconds">
        <option>00&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        <option>32</option>
        <option>33</option>
        <option>34</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>36</option>
        <option>37</option>
        <option>38</option>
        <option>39</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>41</option>
        <option>42</option>
        <option>43</option>
        <option>44</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>46</option>
        <option>47</option>
        <option>48</option>
        <option>49</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>51</option>
        <option>52</option>
        <option>53</option>
        <option>54</option>
        <option>55</option>
        <option>56</option>
        <option>57</option>
        <option>58</option>
        <option>59</option>
      </select>
      <button id="quiter">Quit</button>
      <button class="starter">Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

PS: Sorry for my initial comment - your code is actually well organized and thought out. I think it was my freak reaction from seeing all the stuff I was going to have to parse and try to understand.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. But this does not solved my problem. The alert box should appear when there is not a input but the user is clicking at start but the alert box should not be appear anymore if there is any input

Comment: @fijiwa65 try this - there is a logic problem I need to find, but that does solve the problem per your comment.

Comment: Thanks for finding the initial issue(s). I have posted an update based on your code (including the same issues) with some ideas for improvement regarding code style. I hope you don't mind. I'd love to get your feedback. @Shmack

Comment: I have to leave, be back later to finish this. There is a problem with the logic for when hours > 0 and seconds == 0

Comment: Thank you. I do not understand quite what the problem with the alert box in my code was. can you explain it

Comment: Not related to the alert. It still works in my external jsfiddle and the code above (using Chrome).

Comment: It should be ready for unit testing now - I think I got everything.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current version of the code, with the initial problem fixed (still getting negative numbers when the timer starts, though)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //Card
  const card = document.getElementById("card");

  //Buttons
  const editer = document.getElementById("editer");
  const reseter = document.getElementById("reseter");
  const x = document.getElementById("close-btn");
  const starter = document.getElementById("starter");
  const quiter = document.getElementById("quiter");

  //"Select"-elements
  const hoursFromSelector = document.getElementById("edt-hours");
  const minutesFromSelector = document.getElementById("edt-minutes");
  const secondsFromSelector = document.getElementById("edt-seconds");

  //For calculation
  const mainclock = document.getElementById("mainclock");

  let interval = null;
  let hours = 0;
  let minutes = 0;
  let seconds = 0;
  let i = true;

    addEventListener("change", () => {
      mainclock.innerHTML = `${hoursFromSelector.value} : ${minutesFromSelector.value} : ${secondsFromSelector.value}`;
    });
    reseter.addEventListener("click", () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
        mainclock.innerHTML = "00 : 00 : 00";
        hoursFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
        minutesFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
        secondsFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
        starter.innerText = "Start";
      });
      //Considered Area
      starter.addEventListener("click", () => {
        if (parseInt(hoursFromSelector.value) === 0 && parseInt(minutesFromSelector.value) === 0 && parseInt(secondsFromSelector.value) === 0) {
          starter.innerText = "Start";
          clearInterval(interval)
          alert("Input needed");
          return;
        } else if (parseInt(hoursFromSelector.value) != 0 || parseInt(minutesFromSelector.value) != 0 || parseInt(secondsFromSelector.value) != 0) {
          card.style.display = "none";
          starter.innerText = "Stop";
        }
          if (!interval) {
            hours = parseInt(hoursFromSelector.value);
            minutes = parseInt(minutesFromSelector.value);
            seconds = parseInt(secondsFromSelector.value);
            interval = setInterval(regulSec, 1000);
          } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
            interval = null;
            starter.innerText = "Resume";
          }
      });
    
    function regulSec() {
      if (minutes == 0 && hours > 0) {
        hours--;
        minutes = 60;
      }
      if (seconds == 0 && seconds > 0) {
        minutes--;
        seconds = 59;
      } else {
        seconds--;
      }
      h = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
      sec = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
      min = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      mainclock.innerHTML = `${h} : ${min} : ${sec} `;
      if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
        starter.innerText = "Start";
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }
    
    //Functions without any actual mathematical reference
    //Showing main-card
    editer.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (i == true) {
        card.style.display = "block";
        i = false;
      } else if (i == false) {
        card.style.display = "none";
        i = true;
      }
    });
    
    //Closing-button for main-card
    x.addEventListener("click", () => {
      card.style.display = "none";
      i = true;
    });
    
    quiter.addEventListener("click", () => {
      confirm("Are you sure that you do not want to save your settings?");
      if (true) {
        card.style.display = "none";
        hoursFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
        minutesFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
        secondsFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
        mainclock.innerHTML = "00 : 00 : 00";
      }
    });
}
```

```css
    body {
  background-color: rgba(253, 253, 10, 0.620);
}

#mainboard {
  margin: 45vh;
}

[a] {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  color: black;
  font-size: 120%;
}

#main-btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1vh;
}

#card {
  width: 20vh;
  height: 20vh;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 3;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #accbee 0%, #e7f0fd 100%);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0px 60px 40px -7px;
}

#start {
  background-color: #4AC33C;
}

#card-hdng {
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
  <div id="mainboard">
    <div a id="mainclock">00 : 00 : 00</div>
    <div id="main-btn">
      <button class="button" id="editer">Edit</button>
      <button class="button" id="reseter">Reset</button>
      <button class="starter" id="starter">Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="display:none" id="card">
    <div id="card-hdng">Settings <button id="close-btn">X</button></div>
    <div id="card-items">
      <label for="edt-hours">Hours</label>
      <select id="edt-hours" placeholder="00">
        <option>00</option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        <option>32</option>
        <option>33</option>
        <option>34</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>36</option>
        <option>37</option>
        <option>38</option>
        <option>39</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>41</option>
        <option>42</option>
        <option>43</option>
        <option>44</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>46</option>
        <option>47</option>
        <option>48</option>
        <option>49</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>51</option>
        <option>52</option>
        <option>53</option>
        <option>54</option>
        <option>55</option>
        <option>56</option>
        <option>57</option>
        <option>58</option>
        <option>59</option>
        <option>60</option>
        <option>61</option>
        <option>62</option>
        <option>63</option>
        <option>64</option>
        <option>65</option>
        <option>66</option>
        <option>67</option>
        <option>68</option>
        <option>69</option>
        <option>70</option>
        <option>71</option>
        <option>72</option>
        <option>73</option>
        <option>74</option>
        <option>75</option>
        <option>76</option>
        <option>77</option>
        <option>78</option>
        <option>79</option>
        <option>80</option>
        <option>81</option>
        <option>82</option>
        <option>83</option>
        <option>84</option>
        <option>85</option>
        <option>86</option>
        <option>87</option>
        <option>88</option>
        <option>89</option>
        <option>90</option>
        <option>91</option>
        <option>92</option>
        <option>93</option>
        <option>94</option>
        <option>95</option>
        <option>96</option>
        <option>97</option>
        <option>98</option>
        <option>99</option>
      </select>
      <label for="edt-minutes">Minutes</label>
      <select id="edt-minutes">
        <option>00&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        <option>32</option>
        <option>33</option>
        <option>34</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>36</option>
        <option>37</option>
        <option>38</option>
        <option>39</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>41</option>
        <option>42</option>
        <option>43</option>
        <option>44</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>46</option>
        <option>47</option>
        <option>48</option>
        <option>49</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>51</option>
        <option>52</option>
        <option>53</option>
        <option>54</option>
        <option>55</option>
        <option>56</option>
        <option>57</option>
        <option>58</option>
        <option>59</option>
      </select>
      <label for="edt-seconds">Seconds</label>
      <select id="edt-seconds">
        <option>00&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
        <option>01</option>
        <option>02</option>
        <option>03</option>
        <option>04</option>
        <option>05</option>
        <option>06</option>
        <option>07</option>
        <option>08</option>
        <option>09</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>11</option>
        <option>12</option>
        <option>13</option>
        <option>14</option>
        <option>15</option>
        <option>16</option>
        <option>17</option>
        <option>18</option>
        <option>19</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>21</option>
        <option>22</option>
        <option>23</option>
        <option>24</option>
        <option>25</option>
        <option>26</option>
        <option>27</option>
        <option>28</option>
        <option>29</option>
        <option>30</option>
        <option>31</option>
        <option>32</option>
        <option>33</option>
        <option>34</option>
        <option>35</option>
        <option>36</option>
        <option>37</option>
        <option>38</option>
        <option>39</option>
        <option>40</option>
        <option>41</option>
        <option>42</option>
        <option>43</option>
        <option>44</option>
        <option>45</option>
        <option>46</option>
        <option>47</option>
        <option>48</option>
        <option>49</option>
        <option>50</option>
        <option>51</option>
        <option>52</option>
        <option>53</option>
        <option>54</option>
        <option>55</option>
        <option>56</option>
        <option>57</option>
        <option>58</option>
        <option>59</option>
      </select>
      <button id="quiter">Quit</button>
      <button class="starter">Start</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank You. Can you explain what the failure was exactly.

Comment: The main problem was that `hours` wasn't being updated until after you verified that it was non-0, meaning that it could never be updated

Answer (score 0):

**Note: This is not a real answer, just based on @shmacks code ([link to the post above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73479675/3842598))**

I also have noticed that something is still broken, depending on whether you select seconds (working afaik), minutes, or hours.

Nevertheless, I recommend:

- using speaking variable and method names
- extracting reused (or "complex") code into methods - complexity depends on the view and knowledge) - e.g. code containing comparisons and calculations.

For example, your `x`, `starter`, and `quiter`
variables. I have just used `editButton` instead of
`editer`, etc.

The `i` variable still troubles me :)

I know, the updated piece of code below is not perfect. I am still new to Javascript and happy to get feedback.

```
window.onload = function() {
  const card = document.getElementById("card");

  const editButton = document.getElementById("editer");
  const resetButton = document.getElementById("reseter");
  const closeButton = document.getElementById("close-btn");
  const startButton = document.getElementById("starter");
  const quitButton = document.getElementById("quiter");

  const hoursFromSelector = document.getElementById("edt-hours");
  const minutesFromSelector = document.getElementById("edt-minutes");
  const secondsFromSelector = document.getElementById("edt-seconds");

  const mainclock = document.getElementById("mainclock");
  let interval = null;
  let hours = Number(hoursFromSelector.innerHTML);
  let minutes = Number(minutesFromSelector.innerHTML);
  let seconds = Number(secondsFromSelector.innerHTML);
  let i = true;

  addEventListener("change", () => {
    mainclock.innerHTML = `${hoursFromSelector.value} : ${minutesFromSelector.value} : ${secondsFromSelector.value}`;
  });

  resetButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    clearInterval(interval);
    resetClock();
    resetSelectedIndexes();
    startButton.innerText = "Start";
  });

  startButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const noTimeSet = hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0
    const anyTimeSet = hours != 0 || minutes != 0 || seconds != 0
    
    if (noTimeSet) {
      startButton.innerText = "Start";
      clearInterval(interval)
      alert("Input needed");
      return;
    }

    if (anyTimeSet) {
      hideCard();
      startButton.innerText = "Stop";
      if (!interval) {
        hours = hoursFromSelector.value;
        minutes = minutesFromSelector.value;
        seconds = secondsFromSelector.value;
        interval = setInterval(regulSec, 1000);
      } else {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
        startButton.innerText = "Resume";
      }
    }
  });

function regulSec() {
  if (minutes == 0 && hours > 0) {
    hours--;
    minutes = 60;
  }
  if (seconds == 0 && seconds > 0) {
    minutes--;
    seconds = 59;
  } else {
    seconds--;
  }
  h = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
  sec = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
  min = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  mainclock.innerHTML = `${h} : ${min} : ${sec} `;
  if (minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {
    startButton.innerText = "Start";
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

editButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (i == true) {
    showCard();
    i = false;
  } else if (i == false) {
    hideCard();
    i = true;
  }
});

closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  hideCard();
  i = true;
});

quitButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  k = confirm("Are you sure that you do not want to save your settings?");
  if (k) {
    hideCard();
    resetSelectedIndexes();
    resetClock();
  }
});
};

function hideCard() {
  card.style.display = "none";
}

function showCard() {
  card.style.display = "block";
}

function resetClock() {
  mainclock.innerHTML = "00 : 00 : 00";
}

function resetSelectedIndexes() {
  hoursFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
  minutesFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
  secondsFromSelector.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: the problem is in the `regulSec()` function. Fix the logic, then it will work fine.

Comment: We're using `setInterval(func, delay)` as described on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval - first parameter described as "A function to be executed every delay milliseconds. The first execution happens after delay milliseconds." If minutes are set, the counter reduces by 1 sec (else block).

Comment: Pretty complex, maybe worth checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041474/javascript-countdown-timer-for-hour-minutes-and-seconds-when-a-start-button-cli

Comment: The other checks, e.g. `hours < 10 ? "0" + hours` apply to all other (second and minutes) states.

Comment: I am sorry, but it appears that I missed your kind comment! It appears that `i` is solely based off of `card.style.display` so you can replace the logic for `i` with that inside of a function for the sake of removing a global variable. You can create classes with specific methods to handle x, y, or z, but it might be overkill in this specific case - though beating dead horses further to death is a favorite pass time for me. But I would generally agree - though I can be laxidasical in performing on par to these programming standards. I remember setInterval - there was some nice way of...

Comment: forcing it to fire before the delay and continue after the chosen delay - I could've sworn that it was `setInterval(function(), delay)` as opposed to `setInterval(function, delay)`. There is actually a really nice idea with javascripts new EMAC standard (I believe is what it is called) where you can create an object whose contents are not in (for a lack of better words) a namespace, so its attributes are immutable upon runtime which from looks of it has made javascript safer from a developer's perspective of protecting their code. I believe this idea is tied to the idea of javascript modules.

Comment: I tried to fix the timer, but all the if else statements make it pretty difficult. Look at this nice implementation: https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-using-javascript

Comment: Yah, I thought about this as a potential solution. Its very important as a programmer to be able to articulate what the program requirements are and even better if you can articulate word for word the logic to accomplish that goal. So with the timer, I said base case I want seconds to decrement if it is greater than 0, which should be obvious, because the function runs every second. Next important case is when seconds is 0 and minutes is greater than 0, I want to decrement minutes and set seconds to 59. Next case is when seconds is 0, minutes is 0, and hours is greater than 0...

Comment: Then I want to decrement hours, set minutes to 59 and seconds to 59. Last case is when hours is 0, minutes is 0, and seconds is 0.